# Capture web traffic grouped by individual TCP streams

Tags: networking, http, tcpdump

As far as I know a HTTP request and response constructs one TCP connection. To debug a web application on a GUI-less server, I'd like to be able to capture these TCP streams in a single distinguishable entity (same color, file, db record, anything).

`tcpdump` can only save IP packets as they arrive or leave, with no ordering or reassembling. `tcpflow` goes one step further to reassemble TCP connections in separate files, but puts send and receive streams in separate files, which makes quick debugging annoying. I'm sure I can write a script or even one-liner to merge related files, but I'm guessing a wrapper around `tcpflow` for this job could introduce complexities which wouldn't exist inside `tcpflow`. Also I'm lazy and looking for a cleaner solution.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could copy (or stream) the pcap file to your desktop and use the Wireshark GUI for packet analysis. Besides the GUI, there is also the `tshark` command (included with Wireshark). Given a stream number, you can get its requests and responses combined in a single output with:

```
$ tshark -q -r http.pcapng -z follow,tcp,ascii,1

===================================================================
Follow: tcp,ascii
Filter: tcp.stream eq 1
Node 0: 10.44.1.8:47833
Node 1: 178.21.112.251:80
77
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
Host: lekensteyn.nl
Accept: */*


        356
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Sun, 29 Jun 2014 10:24:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://lekensteyn.nl/

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.7</center>
</body>
</html>

===================================================================
```

Refer to the manual page of `tshark` for more details. Basically, `-q` suppresses the normal packet display, `-r http.pcapng` selects the capture file and `-z follow,...` is the equivalent of the *Follow TCP Stream* in the GUI. Unfortunately, you must repeat this command for every stream, not really ideal.

As for streaming a connection to the Wireshark GUI, you could use this command:

```
ssh you@server 'tcpdump -w - "tcp port 80"' | wireshark -i - -k
```

If this is still not what you are looking for, then you could consider setting up a proxy and then logging everything through that proxy.

Comment: (in Wireshark presumably using right click -> "follow tcp stream")

Comment: The ssh trick rocks. I did not know that GUI apps could take input from stdin.